# css is working within sharepoint designer, but not browser

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, css, browser-compatibility

I am creating a homepage currently with sharepoint designer 2010 and I am trying to sandbox the main page. Though when using my CSS sheet with the aspx file it works file in the designer application, but when I preview with the browser nothing happens as if I did no css at all.

here is my code if that helps, and the name of my style sheet is "Style"

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs3"       Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls"       Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs2" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server.WebControls"Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs1" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs0" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full"  %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities"    Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint,     Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import     Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI,     Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register     Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages"     Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%    $Resources:wss,multipages_homelink_text%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/> 
- 
<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server"><img     src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='1' height='1' alt="" /></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
        <label class="ms-hidden">
<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/></label>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server">
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent runat="server" UIVersion="<=3">
<contenttemplate>

    <style type="text/css">
    td.ms-titleareaframe, .ms-pagetitleareaframe 
    {
        height: 10px;
    }

    div.ms-titleareaframe 
    {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .ms-pagetitleareaframe table 
    {
        background: none;
        height: 10px;
    }

    </style>
</contenttemplate>

</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<meta name="CollaborationServer" content="SharePoint Team Web Site" />
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
var navBarHelpOverrideKey = "WSSEndUser";
// ]]>
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server"
    ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server"/>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
.ms-bodyareaframe {
padding: 0px;
 }
```

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<div id="header"><img alt="banner" class="banner" src="images/Homepage     banner.png" /></div>
<div id="navigation">
<ul id="naviagtion">
<li><a href="#">CustomerPortal</a></li>
<li><a href="#">KnowledgeBase</a></li>
<li><a href="#">NewEmployee</a></li>
<li><a href="#">StatusReport</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="ticketapp"></div>
<div id="public"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Have you used a profiler (opened via F12 in all the major browsers) to validate the CSS file is indeed being loaded & not throwing a 404? In my experience, people will have issues with relative paths that work in SPD but not the browser - because they create the path as relative to the masterpage (i.e. inside _catalogs) instead of relative to the ASPX page that is inheriting from the masterpage at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things you can do:

1. Use Inspect Element to check is your CSS file properly loading.
2. Try to clear the "Cached images and files" in your browser and reload your page again.